# Do votes to close as "Not Constructive" outweigh votes to close as "Off Topic"?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, closed-questions

A moment ago I voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513128/using-assert-for-error-handling) as I found it to be off-topic.  When I got there, there were 2 votes to close as "Non-Constructive" and two votes as "Off Topic."  I cast the third Off Topic vote.

I expected to find the question closed as OT, since I had cast the 5th vote and it was a tie-breaking vote.  But in fact, it was closed as NC.

Why was this post closed as not constructive, rather than off topic?

Not sure if this is a feature or a bug, so I'm asking.

Comment: Maybe your eyes deceived you?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is if 1 of the votes was just for "off topic" and the other was for "off topic belongs on [some other site]" and the system doesn't see those as the same. *shrugs* I guess a dev would have to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reviewing the voting data, I see three votes for "Not Constructive" and two for "Off Topic". You *did* vote OT, and cast the last vote, but with a majority for NC that reason won out.

I'm not rightly sure why it would've appeared that the split was 2 and 2 when you voted.

Comment: hm, I'm pretty sure it displayed as tied.